# Internal Deep Linking is not working with Huawei phones?

Tags: android, android-manifest, huawei-mobile-services, android-deep-link, androidexported

In my application, I have an activity for internal deep linking. It is working as expected for Google Play Services supported phones but not for HMS supported phones. It is giving me an error for Huawei phones as follows ⤵️

```
No apps can perform this action
```

[image]

But if I make `android:exported="true"` it is working. But for security purposes, I am not able to do this.

```html
        <activity
            android:name=".InternalDeepLinkActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="myScheme" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Basically, I need it to work for Huawei phone with `android:exported="false"`

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to having different flavors installed on the phone at the same time. So basically, I removed the other flavors from my hms supported device, and it worked

You might not see other flavors in this case, you may use adb commands to remove it from your phone

Comment: this saved hours for us. thanks